# LabVIEW and .NET application

Tags: .net, labview

I wrote a simple library in .NET and the APIs in the library are accessed by a VI in LabVIEW. I noticed that if I want to access the .NET library from multiple VIs then LabVIEW creates a thread per VI.

What I want to do is to use a process per VI. Is this even possible ?

Eg.

Process 1: the VI A accesses the .NET library 
Process 2: the VI B accesses the .NET library

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It looks like adding  "allowmultipleinstances = TRUE"  in ini file worked. Thanks for taking a look !